# leveldb semantic error, continuously receiving errors from podfiles

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, cocoapods, leveldb

I was trying to run my application in the simulator and all of a sudden I receive an error from *leveldb-library* podfile that I think I never touched.

The error comes from a line of code inside the file and says  `No member named 'NoBarrier_Store' in 'std::__1::atomic<unsigned long>'`
I don't know what to do here since I don't think to have touched any of this podfile ever.
the only thing that I've done and maybe has something to do with this errors is installing a deprecated library. It's called ImagePicker and maybe that installation had some interference with the other podFiles. But apart from that I don't think to have done anything influential.

Depending on when I run I receive some other errors from other podfiles such as **Lottie-ios** and **nanopb** that I cannot understand.

I don't know what to do now, I've already tried to pod install all the pods from terminal but nothing changed...
Thanks to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal for your project location and use these below commands:-

```
step 1:- open podfile
step 2:- copy your all pods and remove all pods and save the file 
step 3:- pod install
step 4:- open podfile
step 5:- paste your all pods again and save the file
step 6:- pod install
step 7:- exit
```

It will solve your problem :) .